# Python Selenium, Can not click list of button in a loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

collect a list of button elements as a list. But when I click one and go back to previous using execute_script() I can not click any other button.

```
btnContainer = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='mx-0']")
for item in btnContainer:
    item.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    self.driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

NB. the code works for the first element in the list and then breaks. The error is "element is not attached to the page document" .I have tried opening the button in a new tab but the website does not support to open the button in a new tab.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You need to add your whole code, which we can copy and run to reproduce the error and maybe help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a new site is loaded then the reference to the previous webelements is lost, so you have to find the elements again. To do this simply run a loop over an index `i` in which you find all the buttons and select the i-th one.

```
for i in range(999):
    btnContainer = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='mx-0']")
    if i < len(btnContainer):
        item = btnContainer[i]
        item.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        self.driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        break
```